# Should I use pip or pip3 to install python3 packages inside of a virtual environment?

Tags: pip, ipython, virtualenv, python-3.4

I have python 2(as default) and 3 on my Linux machine. I created a virtual environment to try out `pandas` with `python3`. So, I ran:

`virtualenv -p python3 pandas_env`

If I type `python` inside of this env it goes to the standard python shell, with python 3 as the default version

```
(panda_env)$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Sep 14 2016, 12:36:27) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

To install ipython, I did:

`(panda_env)$ pip install ipython`

now, running ipython, it defaults to python2 instead of 3

```
(panda_env)$ ipython
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

With a `WARNING` saying to install ipython inside virtualenv. I thought did installed ipython inside the environment, and why is it using python2.x by default?

How do I install ipython inside virtualenv correctly, and how can I make ipython use 3.x instead of 2.x?

Also, should I use `pip` or `pip3` to install packages inside a virtualenv?

Comment: `python $(which ipython)`? I think you probably didn't install the ipython in virtualenv successfully.

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked,.. but should i `pip install <package>` or `pip3 install <package>` inside this environment in future .. For example, i created this environment to work out on pandas. To install pandas and its depended modules, should i use `pip install pandas` or `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: yeah, i haven't installed it correctly, that's what the interpreter says when i do `ipython` on the shell inside the environment. Can u plz help on how to install them properly

Comment: Try `which pip` and `which pip3` to see if each is inside the virtualenv. I think they both should be, in which case they should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: for `(env)$ which pip` i get `~/panda_env/bin/pip` and,
for `(env)$ which pip3` i get `~/panda_env/bin/pip3`

Comment: Post the output of `pip install ipython` here. If you think you already installed it, try `pip uninstall ipython` and also post the output here.

Comment: @PhilipTzou,.. 
`(panda_env)$ pip install ipython
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in ./panda_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Cleaning up...`

Answer (score 0):

Note, for python > 3.3 it's recommended you start a virtual environment with the `pyvenv` command. This has now been deprecated as of python > 3.6 in favor of `python3 -m venv <environment name>` (via https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

In answer to your question, I don't believe it matters based on this check:

```
# start enviroment
$ python3 -m venv test_env; source test_env/bin/activate

# check python version 
(test_env) $ python --version
Python 3.6.0

# check pip and pip3
(test_env) $ which pip
~/Documents/test_env/bin/pip
(test_env) $ which pip3
~/Documents/test_env/bin/pip3

# The pip commands are different, but if we check their versions they are the same and both appear to be using python3.
(test_env) $ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from ~/test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
(test_env) $ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from ~/test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

# In fact the binaries for pip and pip3 within the environment are identical as you can see with this.
(test_env) $ diff ~/Documents/test_env/bin/pip ~/Documents/test_env/bin/pip3

# Checking with ipython
(test_env) $ pip install ipython
(test_env) $ ipython 
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 24 2016, 08:01:42)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to work with virtual environments is to download anaconda and use the conda version control system:

- Works exactly the same way for all versions of python
- Python is treated as just another package as part of the environment
- Everything related to an environment is stored in one folder
- You can see revision history and rollback to previous versions of the environment if something stops working

Comment: This doesn't really answer the op's question. Besides, Anaconda might work for your needs, but it can be a hindrance in other applications.

Comment: I have never come across a situation where it might be a hinderance. Can you give an example?

Comment: Web development, I've also had it interfere with homebrew, making python portable - it's easier just to send code with a requirements.txt file and then running `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: why is this "the easiest"? What makes it easier than any other methods?